# How do I change the font size of a sections header at a specific scroll point?

Tags: javascript

This may be a little complicated, as I only have a little coding knowledge with JS, but I am pretty good and figuring things out and following directions.

First, I will start off with a bit of info on the page I am creating.

I am designing a wordpress page using elementor. This page consists of a few sections. Each section has a title header at the top.

I have made each section sticky to the top and raised the z index of the following section to give a certain effect.

The very first section has a nav menu in the middle, which gets hidden when you cover it with the next section. I though a cool idea would be...

1. Have the second section stick to the top with 0 margin at the top
2. have the third section stick to the top with enough margin to keep the title at the top of the previous section, thus allowing it to be used as an link and ancor it to that section.
3. This process repeats for the next two sections, and when at the last section, you have the title showing of each of the previous sections.

So far I have gotten this to work, but the only issue is that I would like the title for section 2 to slowly shrink as section 3 gets close to it, allowing the so called menu I am creating to take up less overall space.

I have this vision in my head and dont know how to do it, and also I am having a difficult time explaining what I want to do, and I wish I could figure out how to get the code on here. It's a little tricky with it being a wordpress site.

I haven't tried many things, but one thing for sure that didn't work was changing font size on scroll. Since the page is sticky, it changes the title for the current section as it approaches the top, instead of changing it as the next section approaches the top.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Intersection Observer API.

Here's a link: [Intersection Observer Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

Add trigger elements like `<div id="trigger-1"></div>` to your page in the places you need to trigger some action like font size change. Then add the following somewhere in your javascript code:

```
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach((elem) => {
    if (elem.isIntersecting) {
      // Change the font size...
    }
  });
});

const triggerElement = document.querySelector('#trigger-1');

observer.observe(triggerElement);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help in pointing me in the right direction. I am new to JS so it will take some time to figure it out and implement this. I will ley you  know if it was a success.